# How to access individual elements from a Keras Input() object

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

**Background:** I have two Sequential models that form a single model in the following format

`model = Sequential([seq_model1, seq_model2])`

The output of `seq_model1` is predetermined so that it is a `tf.Tensor(shape=(None,5), dtype=float32)`. Therefore, the input of `seq_model2` could be written as `keras.layers.Input(shape(5,))`.

**How can I access the individual input elements of the `Input()` layer of `seq_model2`?**

The `Input()` object acts as a sort of placeholder for the incoming data, so it doesn't actually have any elements you can access. This is verified through the following code:

```
# Define arbitrary input layer
inputs = keras.layers.Input(shape=(5,)) # Returns -> <KerasTensor: shape=(None, 5) dtype=float32>

# Attempt to access an individual element
a = inputs[0] # Returns -> <KerasTensor: shape=(5,) dtype=float32>

# Access an element outside the known shape range
b = inputs[20] # Returns -> <KerasTensor: shape=(5,) dtype=float32>
```

We can see that `inputs` is not iterable in the traditional sense and whether you call its first element, `a` or an element outside the known range, `b`, it returns a `tf.Tensor` with the same shape as `inputs`. I would like my `seq_model2` to be able to access the individual elements of `inputs` to perform custom calculations dependent on said individual elements.

**Is it even possible to access individual values from the `Input` layer? or is this type of operation not currently supported since `Input()` is only a placeholder and not an actual iterable tensor?**

Comment: Try: `a = inputs[:, 0]`, since you are forgetting the batch dimension. It should work then.

Answer (score 0):

So, lets start it with the Sequential Models, Now, Consider I have two sequential models in keras as shown below,

```
clear_session()
model1 = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Input(shape=(224,224,3)),
    keras.layers.Conv2D(64, 3, padding='same'),
    keras.layers.Dense(3, activation='softmax')
])
```

```
#clear_session()
model2 = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Input(shape=(128,128,1)),
    keras.layers.Conv2D(64, 3, padding='same'),
    keras.layers.Dense(3, activation='softmax')
])
```

Now, I have to merge these two sequential models into one,

```
final_model = keras.Sequential([model1, model2])
```

Now, I can access the these two model as an individual layers, which can be seen below,

```
final_model.layers[0].summary()
#Summary of model 1
```

[image]

```
final_model.layers[1].summary()
#Summary of Model 2
```

[image]

I can also retrieve individual layers of each model as same as I did above, as an example I can access the input layer of model 2 also.

```
final_model.layers[1].layers[0].input
```

Output:

```
<KerasTensor: shape=(None, 128, 128, 1) dtype=float32 (created by layer 'input_2')>
```

To Access the Ith element of a layer is

```
#To Access the Output of *ith* element of any layer is
# if my input size is (64, 224, 224, 3)
# then 64 -> batch-size
# (224, 224) -> (width, height)
# 3 -> no of channels
# e.g. so, here if I want to access all the elements of #batch no 10 then I will do...
final_model.layers[1].layers[0].output[i,:,:,:] # i = 10
```

Output

```
<KerasTensor: shape=(128, 128, 1) dtype=float32 (created by layer 'tf.__operators__.getitem_4')>
```

```
#To access the input of *ith* element of any layer is
#Same as before but this time I want to access the last #channel of model along all the batches

final_model.layers[1].layers[0].input[:,:,:,-1] # i = -1
```

Output

```
<KerasTensor: shape=(None, 128, 128) dtype=float32 (created by layer 'tf.__operators__.getitem_5')>
```

Comment: This is all fine and good, but instead of accessing the individual layers of `final_model`, I'd like to access individual elements within the layer you've identified. Using your example of `model1`, its output layer has a shape of (None, 128,128,3) which you're using to feed into `model2` as an input. But in the project I'm trying to code, I need to access, say the i-th element, of (None, 128, 128, i) of this layer and use it in a custom calculation within a SubClass layer within `model2`. Thanks,